What size exhaust vent for 4 clothes dyers going 60’ with 1 elbow?
What size exhaust vent do I need for 4 clothes dryers to go 60’ with 1 elbow?

Is this a commercial installation? 60’ for one dryer usually requires a booster fan unit.

You usually don't share vents for exhausting devices. It's not a good strategy because it can result in reduced or backward flow. You want sufficient flow to prevent heat danger or dryer damage, and you want sufficient velocity to prevent settling out of lint.
So you want four 4" ducts. Or larger, if the dryer literature calls for it at that length. (Read the manual.)
